# Dependency injection using constructor for the test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

My `FixValueConceptIntegration` class has a constructor and it looks like this:

```
private ReferenceConceptHelper referenceConceptHelper;

private ConceptClientFacade conceptClientExternalFacade;
public FixValueConceptIntegration()
{
  referenceConceptHelper = JournalSingletonFactory.getInstance().getSingletonInstance(ReferenceConceptHelper.class);
  conceptClientExternalFacade = JournalSingletonFactory.getInstance().getSingletonInstance(ConceptClientFacade.class);
}
```

So now I'm going to test it using [Mockito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockito).

If we have a constructor like

```
  public FixValueConceptIntegration(ReferenceConceptHelper referenceConceptHelper, ConceptClientFacade conceptClientExternalFacade)
  {
    this.referenceConceptHelper = referenceConceptHelper
    this.conceptClientExternalFacade = conceptClientExternalFacade
  }
```

I know it is easy to initialize when we are going to testing the class. Because we can just mock the `ReferenceConceptHelper` and `ConceptClientFacade` classes.
Then we can use it at the `@BeforeMethod` like this:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod()
{
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  fixValueConceptIntegration = new FixValueConceptIntegration(referenceConceptHelper, conceptClientExternalFacade);
}
```

Then all the dependencies will inject to the constructor and no worries.
So here the problem is I can't figure out how to inject these dependencies (by mocking) to the above testable class.

Comment: Just use `@Mock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended my test class with `TestNGBase` which extends `PowerMockTestCase`.
And then add `registerMockSingleton` method to the `TestNGBase` class like this;

```
protected <E, I extends E> void registerMockSingleton(Class<E> typeInterface, I mock)
  {
    delegate.registerMockSingleton(typeInterface, mock);
  }
```

Then inject mock dependencies to the constructor like this way;

```
@Override
  public void performSetup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    registerMockSingleton(ReferenceConceptHelper.class,mockReferenceConceptHelper);
    registerMockSingleton(ConceptClientFacade.class,mockConceptClientExternalFacade);
    fixValueConceptIntegration = new FixValueConceptIntegration();
  }

  @Override
  protected void performTearDown() throws Exception
  {
    fixValueConceptIntegration = null;
  }
```

All solved!!!
*(My testable class constructor doesn't inject dependencies to with constructor 
 arguments.Thats why I solved my problem like this)*

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `mock` (`org.mockito.Mockito.mock`) method for the class and the `when` method to mock the method calls:

```
@Test
public void yourTest() {

    ReferenceConceptHelper referenceConceptHelper = mock(ReferenceConceptHelper .class);
    when(referenceConceptHelper.someMethod(any()).thenReturn("hello");

    ConceptClientFacade conceptClientExternalFacade = mock(ConceptClientExternalFacade.class);
    when(conceptClientExternalFacade.someMethod(any()).thenReturn("world");

    FixValueConceptIntegration integration = new FixValueConceptIntegration(referenceConceptHelper, conceptClientExternalFacade);
    assertEquals("hello world", integration.methodThatYouWouldLikeToTest());
}
```

In this case, you do not need to use the `@BeforeMethod` or call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`. For unit tests, the `initMocks` are only useful if you do not have access directly to the class injected (typically when you are using field injection).

But if you would like to use the annotations (I personally don't like), you can do something like that:

```
@InjectMocks
private FixValueConceptIntegration integration;

@Mock
private ReferenceConceptHelper referenceConceptHelper;

@Mock
private ConceptClientFacade conceptClientFacade;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(referenceConceptHelper.someMethod(any()).thenReturn("hello");
    when(conceptClientExternalFacade.someMethod(any()).thenReturn("world");
}

@Test
public void yourTest() {
    assertEquals("hello world", integration.methodThatYouWouldLikeToTest());
}
```

Comment: Dherik Just check My constructor.It is not in that type.I don't have any arguments inside it.

Comment: Do you have a `ReferenceConceptHelper` and `ConceptClientFacade`, right?

Comment: yes But It doesn't call any methods.It is inside the constructor and Some other getInstance methods use ReferenceConceptHelper and ConceptClientFacade classes.

Comment: Just call the method you would like to test on `integration`.

Comment: Ok Now I did like this.Just create a instance of `FixValueConceptIntegration` as `integration` and then call to my method. Didn't consider on `ReferenceConceptHelper` and `ConceptClientFacade` classes.then it shows java.lang.IllegalStateException: ReferenceConceptHelper is not registered as a singleton in the factory.

Comment: I edited to show you the alternative, with `initMocks`

Comment: Thnkyou for your answers and +1 for all.But It was not actual answer that I hope.